# How can I put the following in the same cell: =K179+J179 and

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I put the following in the same cell:  `=K179+J179`   and    `=ROUND(L179,2)`?

I only want the amount shown to be nothing beyond 2 decimal places, so that the total of the column is not skewed because of multiple decimal places.

Comment: Do you mean you want the two values shown side-by-side? An example might help to clarify exactly what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Its not quite clear what you are looking for, but probably something like this.  You can put as many arithmetic operations or functions as you like as a parameter.

```
=Round(K179+J179, 2)
```

or

```
=Round(K179+J179+L179, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have two columns of data in K and L that you are trying to sum together but round to 2 decimal points

Currently you have in column L some like

```
=K[row#]+J[row#]
```

then in column M you have something like

```
=ROUND(L[ROW#],2)
```

So put this all in column L and not have Column M. You can in Column L put

```
 =ROUND(K[row#]+J[row#],2)
```

specifically for your example

```
=ROUND(K179+J179,2)
```